# Network configuration fault

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, routing

I'm moving my router from Rpi with Rasbian to another pc device with ubuntu server 14. 
I have:
- local network 10.0.0.0/16, with my router gateway 10.0.0.1
- lte usb device 192.168.8.1 in network 192.168.8.0/24 
- lte usb device 192.168.10.1 in network  192.168.10.0/24

I have moved all network settings with modified iptables rules, firstly I only want to forward traffic from my local network via eth2 (192.168.10.1).
With following settings I doesn't work.

First I noticed what adding 'ip route add default 192.168.10.1' enable internet connections in my local network, but when i changed default gateway to  192.168.8.1 or change '-A PREROUTING -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff' to '-A PREROUTING -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff' it doesn't work but on my previous configuration on RPI this changes don't break internet network.

Secondly without 'ip route add default 192.168.10.1' when i'm trying to connect to some server i have in kern.log:

```
Mar 24 14:16:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1299.607243] '[POSTROUTING]'IN= OUT=eth2         SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=5925 DF PR                                                        OTO=TCP SPT=59745 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:16:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1299.698118] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10                                                         LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59745 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Mar 24 14:16:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1300.695494] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10                                                         LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59745 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Mar 24 14:16:30 ubuntu kernel: [ 1302.698119] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10                                                         LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59745 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Mar 24 14:16:34 ubuntu kernel: [ 1306.698124] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10                                                         LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59745 WINDOW=29200  RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

and with  'ip route add default 192.168.10.1' i have:

```
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1479.922360] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8796 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1479.922385] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth0 OUT=eth2 MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=8796 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1479.922392] '[POSTROUTING]'IN= OUT=eth2 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=8796 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.006939] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.006956] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth2 OUT=eth0 MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=10.0.0.129 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.007197] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8797 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=16450 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.007211] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth0 OUT=eth2 MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=8797 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=16450 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.009327] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=8798 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=16450 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.009341] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth0 OUT=eth2 MAC=00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb:e8:39:35:3a:c9:83:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.129 DST=94.23.42.140 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=8798 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59749 DPT=80 WINDOW=16450 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.062812] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=39937 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.062826] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth2 OUT=eth0 MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=10.0.0.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=39937 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.063815] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=39938 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.063834] '[FORWARD]'IN=eth2 OUT=eth0 MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=10.0.0.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=39938 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 MARK=0x2
Mar 24 14:19:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 1480.063850] '[PREROUTING]'IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64:00:0d:87:8e:4b:ac:08:00 SRC=94.23.42.140 DST=192.168.10.10 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=39939 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=59749 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Does anybody can tell me is that iptables problem or something connected with ubuntu 14 os, or I have forgotten some configurations?

Thanks in advance!

**My settings**

**ifconfig**

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:4f:4b:79:eb
      inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21e:4fff:fe4b:79eb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3477 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:277674 (277.6 KB)  TX bytes:3262888 (3.2 MB)
      Interrupt:21 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
      inet addr:192.168.8.10  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:15975 (15.9 KB)  TX bytes:1018 (1.0 KB)

eth2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
      inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:3616 (3.6 KB)  TX bytes:660 (660.0 B)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:5068 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5068 (5.0 KB)
```

**iproute**

```
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.10
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10
```

**ip route show table upeth1**

```
default via 192.168.8.1 dev eth1
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.10
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10
```

**ip route show table upeth2**

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth1
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.10
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10
```

**rt_tables**

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep

201     upeth1
202     upeth2
```

**iptables-save**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [76:12773]
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "\'[INPUT]\'"
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "\'[FORWARD]\'"
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m mark --mark 0x2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m mark --mark 0x1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [28:6364]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:201]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:136]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "\'[POSTROUTING]\'"
-A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [136:17065]
:INPUT ACCEPT [82:7193]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [24:1606]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [77:13117]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [101:14723]
-A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "\'[PREROUTING]\'"
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.8.1/32 -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.10.1/32 -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -p udp -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -m connmark --mark 0x1 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -m connmark --mark 0x2 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [137:17105]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [77:13117]
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j TRACE
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j TRACE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 24 14:03:06 2016
```

**ip rule**

```
0:      from all lookup local
32762:  from all fwmark 0x2 lookup upeth2
32763:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup upeth1
32764:  from all fwmark 0x2 lookup upeth2
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup upeth1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward**

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we discuss IP tables, the first part of your question, lets talk about your "ROUTER".

1. Post your `/etc/network/interfaces` file
2. The "ROUTER" you are moving. "The DEVICE" is the "PC, Ubuntu 14.04" with three Ethernet cards installed?
3. The MAC addresses of

   `eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64`
   `eth2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64`

   are the same.
4. Should one of these Ethernet cards be a virtual interface? IE: `eth0:1`

Duplicate MACs are "allowed", as far as any out-of-the-box Ethernet switch is concerned-- they just cause a problem that will interrupt network connectivity to each host in question. The problem is a constantly changing switching table.

If there are two hosts, both with the same MAC address, then the switch will update it's MAC table every time it receives a frame from either host. The connectivity of either host will be on and off and inconsistent.

5. What the default gateway of the router?
6. Is there a network device between the router and the WAN interface, is there a managed switch attached to the network?
7. **IP tables**

   -A PREROUTING -d `192.168.8.1/32` -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff

   -A PREROUTING -d `192.168.10.1/32` -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff

Should this be `192.168.8.1/24`
Should this be `192.168.10.1/24`